# Is there a term like PTSD for an event you haven’t experienced yet?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Is there a way to describe a dread over an event in the future, which is nearly pathological?

Comment: Yes: a [**phobia**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/phobia) is an extreme or irrational fear of or aversion to something.

Comment: I would like some clarification on  the nature of the impending event. Is it life-threatening, or an everyday minor  conflict, or maybe  imagined...?

Comment: @WeatherVane Not usually of events, though

Comment: The magnitude of the event could be low or high. I thought of climate anxiety, but also the dread of a smaller, less significant event. Maybe awaiting a sentence, or a meeting where you have to explain a failure to the boss, or getting the bill from an expensive surgery.

Answer (score 3):

***Anticipatory anxiety***

> *Anticipatory anxiety* is the fear and dread you experience before the event. It’s what’s at play when you spend weeks dreading the results of medical appointment...

[Anxiety Canada](https://www.anxietycanada.com/articles/anticipatory-anxiety/)

> ***Anticipatory anxiety*** refers to a persistent and often disabling fear of another panic attack. More specifically, the anticipated, though unlikely somatic (heart attack), psychological (loss of control, madness), and/or social (embarrassment, humiliation) consequences of panic attacks are the focus of this fear.

> Panic-related behavioral changes include avoidance of activities or situations that may precipitate a panic attack (e.g., exercising or crowded places). If this avoidance pertains to agoraphobic situations and becomes prominent and disabling, a diagnosis of agoraphobia may also be considered.

[Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/anticipatory-anxiety)

Like PTSD , Anticipatory Anxiety may be disabling, but can be treated.

See...[**Anticipatory Anxiety**: The Suffering and Solutions](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/debunking-myths-the-mind/201101/anticipatory-anxiety-the-suffering-and-solutions) in Psychology Today

Comment: For the last 20 years at least, _disorder_  seems to be the preferred term for whatever  kind of psychological or mental syndrome. Somewhat the way Cancer, "the big C",  was used many years ago...